# Proper JSON formatting

Tags: json

I am configuring a json file that contains airflow connections, which are loaded in the backend when I launch my airflow server.

One of the fields, requires me to stringify a dictionary pretty much. I'm having some trouble with the syntax however. I understand that in JSON,
`\"` replaces double quotes, but I must be missed something here. Here's an example:

```
"{\"extra__google_cloud_platform__key_json\":
            \"{
                \"type\": \"service_account\",
                \"project_id\": \"sample-project-id123\",
                \"private_key_id\": \"sample_key_id\"
               }"
 }"
```

In VS Code, this field is underlined in red, saying things like "Unexpected End of String" and "Colon Expected".

What am I missing here?

Comment: hm, it appears there's a missing backslash in front of the double-quote after the dictionary-closing `}`.

Comment: Question is tagged Python, but I see no Python code. Is this supposed to be a Python string literal?

Comment: @TurePålsson Right, I removed that tag. This is code in a .json file.

Comment: The fragment you posted is not JSON, it's a JSON (improperly) encoded as JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want just json  backlash chars  should be removed

```
var json= {
  "extra__google_cloud_platform__key_json": {
    "type": "service_account",
    "project_id": "sample-project-id123",
    "private_key_id": "sample_key_id"
  }
}
```

if you want to convert the json to string,  it should be in one line

```
var jsonString="{\"extra__google_cloud_platform__key_json\":{\"type\":\"service_account\",\"project_id\":\"sample-project-id123\",\"private_key_id\":\"sample_key_id\"}}";
```

or you can create a json string

```
var jsonString= JSON.stringify(json);
```

in your string you have a bug  - an extra \ " before  {

```
           \"{
                \"type\": \"service_account\",
```

if you remove it  and  connect all lines with + , then it will be working too.

```
var jsonString=
"{"+
" \"extra__google_cloud_platform__key_json\":" +
      " {" +
          " \"type\":\"service_account\"," +
          " \"project_id\":\"sample-project-id123\"," +
          " \"private_key_id\":\"sample_key_id\""+
      " }" +
 "}";
```

or this is working in javascript too

```
var jsonString=
'{'+
' \"extra__google_cloud_platform__key_json\":  '+
      ' {' +
          ' \"type\":\"service_account\", '+
          ' \"project_id\":\"sample-project-id123\", '+
          ' \"private_key_id\":\"sample_key_id\"  '+
      ' }' +
 '}';
```

Comment: Well, my issue was that I had to wrap this entire dict in a double quotes. So to read the double quotes, I had to include the backlash chars.

Comment: @nick_rinaldi You should be more clear, i updated my answer.

Comment: Apologies, I'm trying to improve clarifying my goal when I ask SO questions. `if you want to convert the json to string, it should be in one line` A question about this out of curiosity... is it possible to have this string span multiple lines? I'm primarily concerned about readability here.

Comment: What do you need a string for? The pure json gives the best readability?

Comment: Airflow loads in this json file upon server launch. It expects to read external connections established within this json, and expects to read every `extra` field as a string https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/howto/connection.html. Airflow expects to decode string data into bytes, so if its a dictionary, error is thrown

Comment: @nick_rinaldi I am not sure why json.stringify is not working for you, but I updated my answer to multiline as you asked.

Comment: I can't invoke json.stringify, this is format in a `connections.json` file. Not in a python file.

Comment: if it is in json file, you can try to use just json as in the start of my answer, it should be working. I use only pure json in my json files.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for me, was to include everything in one line.